# continuously play mp4 file in html5

Tags: html, nginx

I am generating a mp4 file from a live stream, sending it to nginx web server and playing it in the browser using html5 video tag. Since the file is being continuously generated the browser stops playing it after some time (say 5 seconds). I want the browser to keep playing the file from where it stopped. If I use the html5 "loop" feature it starts again from the beginning. Is there some configuration/setting in nginx or html5 which will allow me to do this?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10328401/html5-how-to-stream-large-mp4-files

Comment: @RecycleRobot: I am doing all that is suggested in that post

Comment: are you using a "Connection": "keep-alive" response header?

Comment: I am setting keepalive_timeout 5 in nginx.conf. But I dont see this header in the 200ok response in the web sniffer.

Comment: How do I set keepalive in the connection request?

Comment: No keepalive header doesnt do it

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a "Connection": "keep-alive" response header and http 1.1 explicitly, you can do so like this:

```
server {
    ...

    location /http/ {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: No keepalive header doesnt do it