# Using bootstrap modal to play local mp4 video on IE11 while it always notify "Do you want to open or save xxx"

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, video

I am trying to use modal to popup and play a local mp4 video.
It works on Chrome, Firefox, IE Edge except the IE11 or older version. It always popup a warning on the bottom "Do you want to open or save xxxx from xxxxx". If I click open, it will open the Films & TV to play the video.

Is there anything I missed from using the bootstrap modal? Or it just what IE works like?

Here is my modal:

```
    <div class="productVideo">
    <a href="#videoModal" data-toggle="modal">
        <img src="../assets/img/product/icon/play-button.png">
    </a>

    <!-- Modal HTML -->
    <div id="videoModal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                        <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" id="video" src="http://jplayer.org/video/m4v/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer.m4v" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Besides, I found [the mp3/mp4 from the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Fundamentals/Audio_and_video_delivery#Debugging_Audio_Video_Issues) could not be played normally in IE, it will warn "Do you want to open or save xxxx from xxxxx", but Chrome could play it normally.

---

#### Update

use 'video' tag instead of 'iframe' works for IE11 now.

Comment: do you have any code to show?

Comment: Try googling it, you're not the only one. Mostly suggestions to update flash player or change allow directx settings.

Comment: Welcome to SO. So that we can help you, you need to post the code you have tried so far.

Comment: @VilasKumkar Just posted the code

Comment: @Tschallacka had already googling the related issue. Most answers are IE issue. But I found some website is using the html5box plugin to play video on IE works fine. So I believe there should be some resolution for this.

Comment: maybe they have flash fallback?

Comment: @Tschallacka I just tried the flash fallback, but the issue still there.

Comment: Are you serving the mp4 as streaming type? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10328401/html5-how-to-stream-large-mp4-files

Comment: @Tschallacka It should not be the issue. I just use the curl to test the response header.  Content-Type: video/mp4, Accept-Ranges: bytes and there is no no Content-Encoding:

Comment: mind updating your question with the headers your server provides?

Comment: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.10.3
Date: Thu, 09 Feb 2017 10:37:11 GMT
Content-Type: video/mp4
Content-Length: 17513309
Last-Modified: Thu, 01 Dec 2016 03:46:43 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "583f9d23-10b3b5d"
Accept-Ranges: bytes