# How to serve large video files from php file

Tags: php, html, web-services, video, video-streaming

I want to run a video file from php file using video live stream .

I used this code in php file after send request to this php file and work very good for videos that less than 40MB but if input more about 40 MB not work html5 player !

this code run on Xampp server .

I think that should be php.ini settings

```
$path = "./video/test.mp4";
$fp = @fopen($path, 'rb');
$size   = filesize($path); // File size
$length = $size;           // Content length
$start  = 0;               // Start byte
$end    = $size - 1;       // End byte
header('Content-type: video/mp4');
header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {
    $c_start = $start;
    $c_end   = $end;
    list(, $range) = explode('=', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 2);
    if (strpos($range, ',') !== false) {
        header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
        header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
        exit;
    }
    if ($range == '-') {
        $c_start = $size - substr($range, 1);
    }else{
        $range  = explode('-', $range);
        $c_start = $range[0];
        $c_end   = (isset($range[1]) && is_numeric($range[1])) ?
$range[1] : $size;
    }
    $c_end = ($c_end > $end) ? $end : $c_end;
    if ($c_start > $c_end || $c_start > $size - 1 || $c_end >= $size) {
        header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
        header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
        exit;
    }
    $start  = $c_start;
    $end    = $c_end;
    $length = $end - $start + 1;
    fseek($fp, $start);
    header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
}
header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
header("Content-Length: ".$length);
$buffer = 1024 * 8;
while(!feof($fp) && ($p = ftell($fp)) <= $end) {
    if ($p + $buffer > $end) {
        $buffer = $end - $p + 1;
    }
    set_time_limit(0);
    echo fread($fp, $buffer);
    ob_flush();
    flush();
}
fclose($fp);
exit();
```

Comment: What error is in your PHP log?

Comment: Please tell me log path on xampp server !

Comment: I have no idea but phpinfo(); will show you.

Comment: The normally PHP error log goes here `\xampp\apache\logs\error.log`

Comment: Please refer to this Answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10328401/html5-how-to-stream-large-mp4-files